# Rails Search with optional parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How would I do a search on a database when the search can provide many optional parameters such as ID, Zip, City, and State? These can either have values or be blank entirely. How would I make a rails query like that?

Answer (score 32):

The usual advice is to move logic to the model and keep the controller as lean as possible. There are different approaches for the filter method, the first one:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(attributes)
    attributes.select { |k, v| v.present? }.reduce(all) do |scope, (key, value)|
      case key.to_sym
      when :id, :zip # direct search
        scope.where(key => value)
      when :city, :state # regexp search
        scope.where(["#{key} ILIKE ?", "%#{value}%"])
      when :order # order=field-(ASC|DESC)
        attribute, order = value.split("-") 
        scope.order("#{self.table_name}.#{attribute} #{order}")
      else # unknown key (do nothing or raise error, as you prefer to)
        scope
      end 
    end  
  end
end
```

A second approach, write a bare `filter` that only uses existing scopes:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  SUPPORTED_FILTERS = [:id, :city, ...]
  scope :id, ->(value) { where(id: value) }
  scope :city, ->(value) { where(city: "%#{value}%") }
  ...

  def self.filter(attributes)
    attributes.slice(*SUPPORTED_FILTERS).reduce(all) do |scope, (key, value)|
      value.present? ? scope.send(key, value) : scope
    end  
  end
end
```

For Rails 5, which now uses ActionController::Parameters, the syntax for the filter method is:

```
def self.filter(attributes)
  attributes.permit(SUPPORTED_FILTERS).to_hash.reduce(all) do |scope, (key, value)|
    value.present? ? scope.send(key, value) : scope
  end  
end
```

Models can be called from anywhere in your app, so they are re-usable and easier to test. Now the controller looks as simple as:

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController::Base
  respond_to :html, :xml

  def index
    @records = Record.filter(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: @tokland I used your solution. It looks more elegant than http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes and http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't this solution have a potential memory leak/DoS attack vulnerability? Ex, someone keeps sending in large query strings and the model keeps key.to_sym'ing the random query strings?

Comment: @Corey: that's a good point. It seems modern Rubies finally garbage-collect symbols, though: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9634

Comment: Just a reminder for anyone using a newer Ruby; for the second solution you need the new lambda syntax. So it will be e.g. `scope :id, ->(value) { where(id: value) }`

Answer (score 17):

You can build up a query:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:city] = city unless city.blank?
conditions[:zip] = zip unless zip.blank?
conditions[:state] = state unless state.blank?
Address.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if I need to run the same type of query in mongoid but with greater than condition in one of the parameter, How can I can do that? Hope you understand!

Answer (score 0):

http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/ is what you need.

```
= text_field_tag 'search[city_like]', ''
= text_field_tag 'search[zip_equals]', ''
= text_field_tag 'search[state_equals]', ''
```

And then just

```
Record.search(params[:search])
```