# How can you conditionally build an ActiveRecord Query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to build a search results page in my rails app (still a noob) and I can't figure out how to build a query the rails way.

For example, if no parameters are present I want to return all results.  If the user passes 1 to n optional parameters in the search form I want to add them to the query.

Next if they have a sort specified "price desc" or "year_built desc" or even a combination of both.

Finally use will_paginate to separate the results

```
# default to all listings
@listings = Mls.all

@listings.where("listing_price > ?", params[:listing_price]) unless params[:listing_price].blank?
# ... bunch of other search options ...
@listings.where("property_type = ?", params[:property_type]) unless params[:property_type].blank?

# order
@listings.order("some order by param") if some sort param
@listings.order("some order by param") if some other sort param

# paginate results
@listings.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Is there a "Rails" way of doing this?

Comment: you should code a loop and scopes

Comment: I don't know if this is really an answer to the question but [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) solved my problem pretty neatly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you seen the (revised) Railscasts episode on advanced searches? Here is the link: http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised

The basic idea is to create a `Search` resource that will process the search params sent in through the form and in the background searches over the model in question (in your case `Mls`)

That way, instead of checking in the controller for the presence of certain parameters (e.g. `params[:listing_price]`) you could handle the conditions in your Search model (models/search.rb):

```
def find_listings
  listings = Mls.order(:name)
  listings = listings.where("listing_price > ?", listing_price) if listing_price.present?
  # ... more condition checking
  listings
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of links:

[Using third-party gems (metasearch)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)

[Code from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480088/rails-search-with-optional-parameters)

Comment: metasearch has nothing to do with conditional search

Answer (score 0):

Here is my scope examples, it will query if array is present

```
scope :tagged_one_of, -> (tags) { tags ? where("tags && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", tags) : all }
scope :tagged_all_of, -> (tags) { tags ? where("tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", tags) : all }
```

example

```
Product.where(filter).where(sub_filter).tagged_one_of(tags_array)
```

More about **scopes** [[here]](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-conditionals)