# Rails best practice: Handling multiple relations in a single controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has a Photo model. These photos can belong to a few other classes, e.g., Topic, User, Tag. I'd like to be able to query all the photos based on different related ids. I have set up nested resources like:

```
resources :topics do
  resources :photos, only: ['index']
end

...

resources :users do
  resources :photos, only: ['index']
end
```

I'm wondering what the best practice is for handling this in the controller.
My initial reaction is to write an if / else block, but this feels very un-ruby.

```
if !params[:user_id].nil?
  # query based on user id
elsif !params[:topic_id].nil?
  # query based on topic id

etc.
```

I also debated setting up controller actions and routing to those, like user_photos#photos, topic_photos#photos.

Or setting up some new controllers: UserPhotosController, TopicPhotosController

None of these feel right and I'm wondering if anyone has some insight or if there is a common design pattern for handling something like this.

This is a Rails 4 project, btw.

Comment: Based on the description you should probably look into polymorphic associations. This will make the logic much simpler. Here is a nice [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) on the concept.

Comment: I don't think I was quite clear about the relations, but polymorphism isn't what I'm looking for. Every photo belongs to a user as well as belonging to a single topic. It's sort of a photo sharing application. I just want a filtered querying system that isn't a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, in Rails 4 you can use [`concerns`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns):

```
concern :imageable do
  resources :photos, only: ['index']
end
resources :topics, concerns: :imageable
resources :users, concerns: :imageable
```

Now, I see two ways to go about this situation.

**Option A**: Move if-else to a method which just get the imageable, i.e. user, tag, topic etc. In your PhotosController:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404

def index
  respond_with photos
end

private

def photos
  @photos ||= imageable ? imageable.photos : Photo.all
end

# Find and cache the imageable based on the id in params.
# Using find instead of find_by_id. This is to ensure ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
# exception in the case of an invalid id passed, which be handled with render_404 method
def imageable
  @imageable ||= begin
    if id = params[:user_id]
      User.find(id)
    elsif id = params[:topic_id]
      Topic.find(id)
    end
  end
end

def render_404
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
    format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
  end
end
```

**Option B**: Change your routes to this instead:

```
resources :photos, only: ['index'] do
  resources :topics
  resources :users
end
```

and then change `TopicsController`, `UsersController`, etc accordingly and then you don't need to create `UserPhotosController`, `TopicPhotosController`, etc.

Comment: I like the idea of moving the conditional to a method. Also, didn't know about concerns in routes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can combine the controller logic in one controller class, then you should do that. I dont see why a selection based on param values should be un-ruby. Thats seems to be the right thing to do.

Comment: Well, my concern is that there are a lot of potential conditions. I don't want a long messy if, elsif, elsif, elsif, elsif ...

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine for you to use that if statement.

Another thing you can do is have your if statements, and then put your params into a hash. Then you can pass this hash into the Model lookup, in the case of wanting to look at photos by a certain user under a certain topic.

Example of this is this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480139/2589358

I found this was a nice way because it is easier to manage adding more params later one, and also it looks cleaner.